# Digital Voltmeter - TriColor LED Output

Tags: voltage-divider, voltage-measurement, voltage-detector

I'm very new to electronics and I wanted to start with something that would hopefully simple, but also useful.

I'd like to make a circuit that can read a DC input voltage (between 9V and 20V) and output to a multicolor LED.  The color would change depending on the sensed voltage.

Can someone please steer me in the correct direction for getting started on this project?  I'm not certain what terms I should be searching or an ICs I can take a look at.

Is this as simple as making a set of voltage dividers and placing my output to the LED's pins in the appropriate location?

EDIT:
OK.  Here's my first attempt/iteration.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbDRkn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If I understand correctly, anything 13VDC or higher should light the LED?  Should I limit current somehow to the IC or will R1 handle it?

Answer (score 4):

There are *many* ways to do what you want.  The simplest is to use a quad comparitor chip such as the LM339.  You simply set up 3 or 4 stages as comparitors - each stage drives a LED.

The LM3914 is an inexpensive chip that contains 10 comparitors, each able to drive a LED.  It is intended for doing bar-graph displays but will work nicely driving fewer LEDs than than 10.  You simply connect several outputs to a single LED - that LED will come on whenever one of those outputs is active.

Now it's your turn.  We've given you a couple of examples - now go and do some searching and reading.  Come back when you have more questions.  We'll help you get where you want to go but you have to show that you are willing to put some effort into the process.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I've updated my question with my first attempt.

Answer (score 2):

You will need some sort of switching circuit, or amplifier, or a mix. This could be an operational amplifier (op-amp), transistor(s), a microprocessor, or no doubt a multitude of ICs. Your requirements are a bit vague, in that the exact behaviour of the LEDs with respect to the voltage could make quite a difference. Also, there are different types of multi-colour LEDs. Some are bi-colour with two pins, where only one colour can show at a time, or there are RGB LEDs, among others. Last (and possibly not least), you haven't said how much current it would be acceptable (or possible) to be drawn from the voltage source(s) you intend to probe.

I think the most flexible IC you should look at would be a comparator IC. Often these come in multiples on a single chip. The LM360 is an example. You would use one input as a reference voltage, set by a potential divider as you rightly pointed out, the other input as the probe, and the output would control the LED (via a current limiting resistor.) For multiple LEDs, use multiple comparators.

In the diagram below, the LED would light when the comparator's output is low. This would happen when the so-called non-inverting input is lower than the inverting input. In other words, the LED would light when the probe senses a voltage lower than 4.5v.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZqIJR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: And don't get hung up on the exact LED. The one shown in the schematic is just the default part number when you create a schematic on this site.